# What user-agent does DownThemAll add on extension convey to servers when executing within 2020 versions of Firefox Browsers? Any easy way to check?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, download-manager

What user-agent does DownThemAll add on extension convey to servers when executing within 2020 versions of Firefox Browsers? Any easy way to check?

The last googled info I could find on this was here:

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/firefox/addon/downthemall/versions/

> Version 2.0.1.1-signed
>   Released Feb. 7, 2011 585.0 KiB
>   Works with Firefox 3.5 - 4.0.*, SeaMonkey 2.0 - 2.1b3
>
> - *flatcurl* renaming mask was fixed
> - OSX: Tools menu icons were fixed
> - Added downloads are scrolled into the view again
> - Access keys added back
> - Dropdowns histories (Directory, Mask, Fast Filtering):
>
>   - If the "Number of Entries to keep" preference is 0 upon upgrade, it will be reset to the default (5). This will only happen
>       once. You may change it back afterwards. This is to accommodate users
>       who inadvertently set it to 0, and now wonder why their histories
>       aren't stored any more
>   - If the Preference is set to 0, then the default values will be used.
> - The **Expose DownThemAll!** in the **User-Agent preference** is now turned **off by default**. Some **naive authenticating proxy servers and web**
>     **applications stopped working when turned on**.
> - The Remove-menus in the manager are now split-menus: You can click the menu item to launch the default action, or click or hover the
>     sub-menu arrow to get to the more fine-grained actions
> - Fixes concerning some third party themes
> - Updated locales, adding French and Traditional Chinese translations
> - Couple of Firefox 4 fixes
> - Minor improvements and fixes
>
> Full release notes
>
> - Source code released under GNU General Public License, version 2.0

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup. Added some "emphasis"

Comment: Are you sure this option even exists in the current version of DownThemAll?

Answer (score 0):

Just download any user-agent checking website. I just have googled [this one](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent). Quote:

> This page shows you what your web browser is sending in the "User-Agent" header for your HTTP requests.

So downloading it with DownThemAll should produce an HTML file with the value DownThemAll sent.